# iphone 4 UIAlertView setAlertViewStyle unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: uialertview, iphone-4

I used the below code to add textfield in UIAlertView. It works fine in Simulator(iOS SDK 5.0) but when i install in device(iOS 4.0.1) i get "Unrecognized selector sent to instance error"

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter your name" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    alert.tag = 9001;

    [alert show];

    [alert release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Test Alert" message:@"what do you want" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"tell me" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

[myAlert addTextFieldWithValue:@"nothing" label:@"say something"];

UITextField * aTextFld = [myAlert textFieldAtIndex: 0];
aTextFld.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
aTextFld.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

[myAlert show];
[myAlert release];
```

Comment: This worked for me, [myAlert addTextFieldWithValue:@"nothing" label:@"say something"];

Answer (score 0):

Include the library from here: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html

Try to use the below code:

```
AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc]; 
    prompt.tag = 100;
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Enter a name" message:@"                  " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Save"];
    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!" message:@"Please enter your name:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter your name";
[alert show];
[alert release];
```